# Why is it not allowed to delete packaged Custom Labels?

Tags: managed-package, isv, deprecation

In our managed package we replaced many custom pages with standard layouts. Now there is a bunch of Custom Labels that were useful before (e.g. for translation) but could be removed from the Managed package.

But this seems to be forbidden. Why? Is there something on the Safe Harbor Roadmap to let us delete them in the near future?

Comment: This is something running in pilot mode. You may be able to delete Labels and other comps.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Salesforce blindly following rule which prevent deleting of any component which is a part of Managed Released package regardless of any version it was used or being used.

However, there is a pilot program running by Salesforce for around 1-2 years which allow to delete many crucial components including custom labels. You may apply to enroll in it.